# Populating data from one data.table to another

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I have a distance matrix (as data.table) showing pairwise distances between a number of items, but not all items are in the matrix. I need to create a larger data.table that has all the missing items populated. I can do this with matrices fairly easily:

```
items=c("a", "b", "c", "d")
small_matrix=matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 3), nrow=2, ncol=2, 
      dimnames=list(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b")))

# create zero matrix of the right size
full_matrix <- matrix(0, ncol=length(items), nrow=length(items),
      dimnames=list(items, items))

# populate items from the small matrix
full_matrix[rownames(small_matrix), colnames(small_matrix)] <- small_matrix
full_matrix
#   a b c d
# a 0 2 0 0
# b 1 3 0 0
# c 0 0 0 0
# d 0 0 0 0
```

What is the equivalent of that in data.table? I can create an 'id' column in small_DT and use it as the key, but I'm not sure how to overwrite items in full_DT that has the same id/column pair.

Comment: Perhaps `library(reshape2);library(data.table);DT <- setDT(melt(small_matrix))[melt(full_matrix)[-3], on=c('Var1', 'Var2')];DT[is.na(value), value:=0];dcast(DT, Var1~Var2, value.var='value', fill=0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's convert to `data.table` and keep the row names as an extra column:

```
dts = as.data.table(small_matrix, keep = T)
#   rn a b
#1:  a 0 2
#2:  b 1 3
dtf = as.data.table(full_matrix, keep = T)
#   rn a b c d
#1:  a 0 0 0 0
#2:  b 0 0 0 0
#3:  c 0 0 0 0
#4:  d 0 0 0 0
```

Now just join on the rows, and assuming small matrix is always a subset you can do the following:

```
dtf[dts, names(dts) := dts, on = 'rn']
dtf
#   rn a b c d
#1:  a 0 2 0 0
#2:  b 1 3 0 0
#3:  c 0 0 0 0
#4:  d 0 0 0 0
```

Above assumes version 1.9.5+. Otherwise you'll need to set the key first.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I knew there had to be a simple way :).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have these two `data.table`:

```
dt1 = as.data.table(small_matrix)

#   a b
#1: 0 2
#2: 1 3

dt2 = as.data.table(full_matrix)

#   a b c d
#1: 0 0 0 0
#2: 0 0 0 0
#3: 0 0 0 0
#4: 0 0 0 0
```

You can't operate like with `data.frame` or `matrix`, eg by doing:

```
dt2[rownames(full_matrix) %in% rownames(small_matrix), names(dt1), with=F] <- dt1
```

This code will raise an error, because to affect new values, you need to use the `:=` operator:

```
dt2[rownames(full_matrix) %in% rownames(small_matrix), names(dt1):=dt1][]

#   a b c d
#1: 0 2 0 0
#2: 1 3 0 0
#3: 0 0 0 0
#4: 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: that `as.list` is unnecessary, and this isn't the same as you'll always fill out top rows only - small matrix can't be on the bottom rows; also `(as.)data.table` works just fine on matrices

Comment: @ ture, I took into account your comment. The only "trick" is to use indexation with rownames, even if I do not see why the OP wants to go with data.table for this subset.